# SharePoint 2010 Certifications

Tags: certification

What are the SP 2010 certifications that are available? (I have both dev and admin experience)

Where to take them?

How much are they?

How do potential employer can verify validity of my certificates?

Is there a genetic MCP or it's always on a subject?

How long are the exams?

What is the minimum score that you need to pass the test?

Comment: though it doesn't answer all your questions, you should look at [the microsoft page that details their exams for SP](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-sharepoint-server.aspx#tab1). Exams will cost in the region of $150, but it depends on where you live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a real example on how to validate or view a certificate.

https://mcp.microsoft.com/authenticate/validatemcp.aspx

use following info
Transcript ID=949948
Access Code=ANTO2040

Comment: All answers are super good and gives me all the answers that I have been looking for. Thanks Mike, Matt and Brandy.

Answer (score 3):

All of your questions and more are answered on the MS Learning site - http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/default.aspx

There are generally 2 paths; one for IT Pros (70-667 and 70-668) and one for devs (70-573 and 70-576).

The first for each path is for a Technical Specialist badge, and then the second is for the Pro badge.

If you pass any exams it will get you a unique MCP number which provides a listing of all of your exams.  There is a URL and passcode that can be provided to people who need to validate your credentials.

Comment: If you already have the knowledge then by all means get the certification. Don't let the certification be the reason you're learning.

Certification shows you take your career seriously but says little about your competence.

Comment: Salam Falak.Good said...

Comment: The MS Certified Master (MCM) and MS Certified Architect (MCA) both take serious time commitments and show a true mastering of the technologies.  I have the utmost respect for those that put in that kind of time as it requires much deeper understanding than the certification courses.  I have seen people pass the certification and still not be able to function in a position.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the SP 2010 certifications that are available? (I have both
>   dev and admin experience)
>
> Where to take them?
>
> How much are they?
>
> How do potential employer can verify validity of my certificates?
>
> Is there a genetic MCP or it's always on a subject?
>
> How long are the exams?
>
> What is the minimum score that you need to pass the test?

In answer to your questions, there are 4 exams to my knowledge, 2 admin 2 dev (i think) there is also the MOS exam which is an office based exam.
You take them at any Prometric exam site (check their website)
they are £88 each at the last check but if you book today (yes really) you will get a buy one get one free.

The MCP site lets people verify and you can create a profile to send them too.

min score is 70% for all exams I think or 700 out of 1000

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Great. Do verification screen shows score as well? just a confirmation that so and so took the certification and passed.

Comment: Prometric site not showing the schedule and exam locations.

Comment: Mitch make sure you pick Microsoft as the technology, its a bit of a strange site to use but t does definitely show the schedule and such you just have to locate your closest test centre first. As for score, hmmm I think you can print your exam sheets, at least you can contact the test centre for them for sure.